# How to get indices of an array and store them in a different array?

Tags: arrays, scala

```
 val x = Array(1,0,0,0,1)
    
 val y = x.zipWithIndex
    
// Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,0), (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1,4))
```

I want to get indices `(0,1,2,3,4)` and store them in a different array .

I used foreach in this fashion but I dont know then how to do any operations .

```
val z = y.foreach({case (a,b)=> print(b)  })
```

This gives me the indices but then if I use z.toString it's an empty string .

How do I solve this ?

Comment: The [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) can be very helpful for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have an array.

```
val x = Array(1,0,0,0,1)
```

> I want to get indices (0,1,2,3,4) and store them in a different array.

```
val y = x.indices.toArray
```

Seems a rather pointless exercise.

Comment: It's not pointless . I am using it to solve binary gap . Your solution is very elegant . I also used x.zipWithIndex.filter({case (a,b)=> a==1}) .

Answer (score 1):

This?

scala> Array(1,0,0,0,1).zipWithIndex.map(_._2)
val res1: Array[Int] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)

See, `[A]foreach(A => Unit):Unit` meaning, foreach takes function from A to Unit and returns Unit.

You need `[A]map(A => B):Array[B]`. Which takes a function from A to B and returns a new Array[B]. In this particular case A and B are the same, Int.

> This gives me the indices but then if I use z.toString it's an empty string .

Well, I'd say `{case (a,b)=> print(b) }` doesn't give you anything, it print b. But b is lost, it can't be used by your program anymore. That is what the type Unit means.

Comment: Thanks . I know how to apply a map function at a very basic level like doubling the values of an array or adding a number to it but I am not able to understand it at a fundamental level .

Comment: That's what I tried to explain.